# act as bluetooth device for another computer/mobile

Tags: debian, usb, bluetooth, microphone, usb-audio

Is there a way to communicate to an USB headset (audio + mic) on a linux computer and then relay the usb communication to another device via bluetooth?

Comment: would this help? https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-send-sound-through-bluetooth-on-linux/

Comment: @Bart , your link explains how to connect an USB headset to linux. I need linux to pose as an usb headset to other devices